# How do shell scripts in /etc/profiled.d/ affect /etc/profile

Tags: bash, scripts

I have written a shell script and placed it in`/etc/profile.d/`.

The script contains the following:

```
if [ ] # Boolean condition is in these brackets.
  then
    shutdown -P 23:00
```

So, when I login I am getting a message that starts:

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile:
Shutdown scheduled for ... 23:00:00 PDT, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.
As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

This is strange to me because I have made no changes to `/etc/profile`.

My question from this has a few parts:

Am I supposed to make a change to `/etc/profile`?

Or is the problem that I am using `shutdown` in `/etc/profile.d/`?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `/etc/profile`, we see:

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

That is, scripts called `*.sh` in `/etc/profile.d` will be executed whenever `/etc/profile` is executed.

When is `/etc/profile` executed? `man bash` (or [Online man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html) shows:

```
When  bash  is  invoked  as  an  interactive  login shell, or as a non-
interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and  executes
commands  from  the  file  /etc/profile,  if  that  file exists.  After
reading that file, it looks  for  ~/.bash_profile,  ~/.bash_login,  and
~/.profile,  in  that  order,  and reads and executes commands from the
first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option  may  be
used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
```

and:

```
 If  bash  is  invoked  with  the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup
 behavior of historical versions of sh as  closely  as  possible,  while
 conforming  to  the  POSIX  standard  as  well.   When  invoked  as  an
 interactive login shell, or a non-interactive shell  with  the  --login
 option,   it   first   attempts  to  read  and  execute  commands  from
 /etc/profile and ~/.profile, in that order.  The --noprofile option may
 be used to inhibit this behavior.
```

All this means that every time you invoke `/etc/profile` (The above shows when `bash` does it, does your `~/.bashrc`?) the scripts will be run.

On your second (and subsequent) invocations of `/etc/profile`, `shutdown` sees that another `shutdown` is active, and complains.

You could put `shutdown -c` before `shutdown -P 23:00` in your script to replace the old `shutdown` with the new `shutdown`.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for the help. That makes sense. I should've thought of using the man pages for bash. I'll try out your suggestion

Comment: After using your recommendation, the error message remains unchanged. Seems I will have to do some more research